# I am new to powershell Deploy Chrome it drops a folder on the remote machine then sits in the "Installing update" and never finishes

Tags: powershell-remoting

## Variables

## $computernames = Get-Content "C:\psexec\Chrome.txt"

$computernames = "NMOTC-sb10-9020"
$sourcefile = "\nmotc-ap-sccm\nmotc_packages\Chrome\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi"

## This section will install the software

foreach ($computer in $computernames)

{

```
$destinationFolder = "\\$computer\c$\Program Files\Google"

#This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.

if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))

{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow Creating Directory $computer\c$\Program Files\google\application\Chrome
    New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory
}
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Copying Update
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Installing Update
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {& cmd /c  msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "i C:\Program Files\google\Chrome\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi"  
} 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Cleaning Up Installation Files
#Remove-Item $destinationFolder -recurse
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code that's in your ScriptBlock locally on a machine you want to install Chrome on does it work?  I've used:

```
msiexec.exe /i "C:\Software\Chrome\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise64.msi" /q /norestart
```

That command has worked for me when running it locally in PowerShell, seems like that should work in your ScriptBlock as well.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I just saw this, and will give it a shot.

Comment: Hi Jason, I tried the line you gave but it was stuck in "Installing Update" I even left for the day and still there the next morning.

Answer (score 0):

## Variables

## $computernames = Get-Content "C:\psexec\Chrome.txt"

$computernames = "xxxx-sb10-3020"
$sourcefile = "\nmotc-ap-sccm\xxxx_packages\Chrome\googlechromestandaloneenterprise.msi"

## This section will install the software

foreach ($computer in $computernames)

{

```
$destinationFolder = "\\$computer\c$\Program Files\Chrome"

#This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.

if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))

{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow Creating Directory $computer\c$\Windows\System32\11.0.19
    New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory
}
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Copying Update
    Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Installing Update
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c msiexec.exe /i "C:\Program Files\Chrome\GoogleChromeStandaloneEnterprise.msi"  
} 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow Cleaning Up Installation Files
Remove-Item $destinationFolder -recurse
```

}
I did get this to work well